# JavaFX + Embedded HTTPS server

Tags: java, jsp, javafx, https, server

I'm looking forward to developing a Java application to send files across the internet;
The main idea is to use a `JavaFX` frontend to control an embedded `HTTPS` server hosting a web page that contains a list of all files needed to be shared, each with a download option.

**What would be the best way to approach this?** I've looked into `Tomcat` (embeddable, supports JSPs) but it seems to be very underdocumented. There's also Spring Boot but it doesn't seem to support JAR packaging (see footnotes: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp).

Can you help me out? Thanks!

PS: I plan on using OpenJDK version 16 on Linux Mint

Comment: What advantage would a UI give you when you could just run Apache, put the needed files in there and allow the directory to be listed?

Comment: Ease of use, I want my application to be very user-friendly

Comment: Not sure exactly what your use cases are, but of course you could make the GUI independent, to, e.g. Apache

Comment: Most end devices of users are non-accessible behind NAT-routers or even carrier grade NAT system. Therefore a web server in an app will not help you much as it's port is not accessible from the Internet. If you really want to try it and embed an web server into an Java app I would recommend [Undertow](https://undertow.io) or [Jetty](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/).

Comment: Springboot starter web will definitely let you embed Tomcat and create a runnable, stand-alone Jar.  Personally, I would create a separate Jar file for the JavaFX maintenance and then communicate with the Web app via a REST API built into the Web app.

Comment: Use https://start.spring.io/ and specify build output to be a Jar.

Comment: Would a REST API be able to start/stop the web app?